# Display array elements in a specific way

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, session, shopping-cart

I am making a session based shopping cart system, and I need some help with displaying the array from the session. My array looks like this:

```
array(5) { [0]=> NULL [1]=> string(5) "TMRS1" [2]=> string(5) "TMRS2" [3]=> string(5) "TMRS1" [4]=> string(5) "TMRS3" }
```

I would like a script to count duplicate elements and display them.

For instance, `TMRS1` would be set to `$name1` (= TMRS1) and `$quantity1` (= 2). The next item would then be `$name2` and `$quantity2` and so on.

Is this possible? You are more than welcome to post if you've got a better idea on how I can display the items in the cart. I just have to be able to pull some data from a database by using the name of the items, and then add up all the prices of the items :)

Comment: why is the quantity for TMRS1 1? I see it twice

Comment: @FuzzyTree sorry, my fault. It is corrected now :)

Comment: TMRS is an item, and the number beside is quantity ?

Comment: @microbe TMRS1, TMRS2 etc. is item id's. The quantity is specified by how many of them, the array contains.

Comment: Why not count items when user click "add to cart" ?
But, in that case you'll need an assosiative array, $item -> $quantity.
Then, create a function called when user click on "add to cart" that search the array, if the item dont exist yet, create a row with item and quantity set to 1, if the item is yet in the cart, change the quatity (increment +1), isnt this more simple ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe you can use [array_count_values()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php)

example from php.net

```
<?php
$array = array(1, "hello", 1, "world", "hello");
print_r(array_count_values($array));
?>
```

The above example will output:

```
Array
(
    [1] => 2
    [hello] => 2
    [world] => 1
)
```

With the array you give:

```
$shopping_cart = array("TMRS1","TMRS2","TMRS1","TMRS3");
$items_count = array_count_values($shopping_cart);

echo "Number of TMRS1 in the cart:".$item_count["TMRS1"];
```

Comment: That does not answer my question. I need the script to give each item a $name(number) and $quantity(number).

Answer (score 0):

This would leave you with an array with the data you need:

```
<?php

$tmrs = array(NULL, "TMRS1", "TMRS2", "TMRS1", "TMRS3");

foreach ($tmrs as $key => $val){
    $duplicateArray[$key]['name'] = "TMRS" . $key; // only the name
    $duplicateArray[$key]['quantity'] = (int) str_replace("TMRS", "", $val); // aquire only the value
}

print_r($duplicateArray);

?>
```

That would return:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [name] => TMRS0
        [quantity] => 0
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [name] => TMRS1
        [quantity] => 1
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [name] => TMRS2
        [quantity] => 2
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [name] => TMRS3
        [quantity] => 1
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [name] => TMRS4
        [quantity] => 3
    )

)
```

You could then output the name or the value like this:

```
<?php echo $duplicateArray[2]['name']; ?>
```

Comment: Sadly, the item is not always called TMRS(number), so I can't use this - but thank you for your comment :)